# Android - Data Binding - String Attribute with Expression

Tags: android

I have been struggling with an almost unsolvable issue with Android lately.
I'm trying to build a custom control that would take one of its value dynamically from a function.
But with no avail.
Here is the attrs.xml entry:

```
<declare-styleable name="BinaryOptionButtonAttrs">
<attr name="binaryText" format="string"/>
<attr name="binaryValue" format="string"/>
<attr name="binaryDirection" format="enum">
    <enum name="up" value="0x00"/>
    <enum name="down" value="0x01"/>
</attr></declare-styleable>
```

Here is the custom control view code:

```
public class BinaryOptionButton extends LinearLayout {
private Context mContext;
private String mText;
private String mValue;
private BINARY_OPTION mDirection;

public BinaryOptionButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public BinaryOptionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    initAttrArray(attrs);
    initBinaryOptionButton();
}

public String getBinaryText() {
    return mText;
}

public void setBinaryText(String mText) {
    this.mText = mText;    }

public String getBinaryValue() {
    return mValue;
}

public void setBinaryValue(String mValue) {
    this.mValue = mValue;        Log.d(this.getClass().getPackage().getName(),
            "BinaryOptionButton.mValue=" + mValue);
}

public BINARY_OPTION getBinaryDirection() {
    return mDirection;
}

public void setBinaryDirection(BINARY_OPTION mDirection) {
    this.mDirection = mDirection;
}

private void initBinaryOptionButton() {

}

private void initAttrArray(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray attrsArray   = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.BinaryOptionButtonAttrs, 0, 0);

    mText = attrsArray.getString(
            R.styleable.BinaryOptionButtonAttrs_binaryText
    );

    mValue = attrsArray.getString(
            R.styleable.BinaryOptionButtonAttrs_binaryValue
    );

    mDirection = BINARY_OPTION.parseInt(attrsArray.getInt(
            R.styleable.BinaryOptionButtonAttrs_binaryDirection,
            BINARY_OPTION.UP.value()
    ));
    Log.d(this.getClass().getPackage().getName(),
            "mText=" + mText);

    Log.d(this.getClass().getPackage().getName(),
            "mValue=" + mValue);

    Log.d(this.getClass().getPackage().getName(),
            "mDirection=" + mDirection);

    attrsArray.recycle();
} }
```

Here is a sample usage of the Custom View:

```
<layout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <import type="Utils"/>
    <variable
        name="HANDLER"
        type="ViewListener"/>
    <variable name="dataCount" type="int"/>
    <variable name="dataVector" type="java.util.List"/>
</data><RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.package.BinaryOptionButton
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
bind:binaryText='@{"BUY"}'
bind:binaryValue="@{Integer.toString(dataCount)}"
bind:binaryDirection="@{Utils.binary(dataVector)}"    
android:onClick='@{() -> HANDLER.onAction("data")}'/></RelativeLayout</layout>
```

The Attribute binaryText shows "BUY". However, the Attributes binaryValue and binaryDirection are NEVER even called!

What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: tried to see generated sources with the binding?

Comment: ... and where do we look for it? Directory name? File name?

Comment: Here is the only file in the dataBinding dir: DataBindingInfo.java [code]package android.databinding.layouts;

import android.databinding.BindingBuildInfo;

@BindingBuildInfo(buildId="7e917fdd-a282-4afe-bf93-be5785860cd8")
public class DataBindingInfo {}[/code]

Comment: Ok. Found it. Here is how it handles the dynamic values: [code]if ((dirtyFlags & 0x1002L) != 0) {
            // api target 1

            this.btn.setBinaryValue(integerToStringData);
        }
        if ((dirtyFlags & 0x1100L) != 0) {
            // api target 1

            this.btn.setBinaryDirection(utilsBinaryDataVector);
        }[/code]

Comment: What is dirtyFlags for? Apparently the "if" conditions are NEVER met.

Answer (score 0):

The Code ABove is Correct. The Attributes were called correctly. The problem was some of the Logging points weren't called for an unknown reason.